# How can I prevent the "Attempting to get the view from an adapter in state TextDocDataAvailable" fail in visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I search my solution, and the main form (frmMain.cs) is within the search results, 2-clicking the line from the "Find Results" pane which should take me to the frmMain.cs file, I often just see a blank (albeit grayed out, not black) window in the IDE. If I then click on that grey foggy nothingness, it tells me, "Attempting to get the view from an adapter in state TextDocDataAvailable"

Closing VS and reopening it solves the issue temporarily (I can then 2-click the frmMain.cs file and view it normally), but is there a way to prevent this revoltin' development from happening at all?

**Note:** I can also, when this occurs, 2-click frmMain.cs in the Solution Explorer; this makes the "visual" part of the form visible in the IDE; I can then right-click and select "View Code" and it works. Odd, though...

Comment: I just had the same thing in Visual Studio 2015. I wish they wouldn't put out such poorly written and unstable software. This is on update 3.. ridiculous !

Comment: Even shift-F5 or Debug -> Terminate All generates this message. Have to kill the process.

Comment: @user2728841: Can you name any company or entity that creates complex software that does not "put out poorly written and unstable software"? Of course, it depends on your definition of such, but I maintain (no pun intended) that all software of a complex nature has more bugs than the coders of it would care to admit.

Comment: I have the same problem in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: same in VS 2017 15.9.27

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened to me when I edited User/AppData/Roaming/Nuget/Nuget.config while Visual Studio was open.  Having done that, attempts tp close Visual Studio or open the NuGet Extension Manage resulted in this error dialog.  I resolved by killing the devenv.exe process, and restarting Visual Studio.

Answer (score 20):

Admittedly a little late to the party... but FWIW - I've had the same issue and was able to close VS2015 by changing from the current tab to another tab and then closing VS2015 and restarting. I just figure that it's better to not have to kill processes manually if you don't have to. :-)

Comment: This is a much better alternative than having to kill the process.  I didn't even have to restart.  Just changed tabs, closed the tab causing the error and moved on.

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I tried to use an exe in a solution which was being used by some other solution.

The solution to this problem can be achieved by killing the devenv.exe process.